# include HTML simplest way

Tags: html, include

I am looking for the simplest solution (no js query, no script, just pure html code) to include some code from an other file.
More precisely, I have two files "index.html" and "content.inc" such that

index.html:

```
<head>
...
</head>


<body>
include content.inc
</body>
```

I tried

but some scrollbars appear and the size is reduce, it's horrible.

Do you have the easy solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way would be to use Javascript or PHP as an INCLUDE file.
http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp

Answer (score 0):

Enable [Server Side Includes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes) on your web server. Configuration details will depend on what web server you run. e.g. apache, nginx, etc.